# Get int instead of pointer from strchr

Tags: c, string

How do I get the index of the first occurrence of a character in a string as an int and not a pointer to its location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two pointers to an array in C, you can simply do:

```
index = later_pointer - base_address;
```

where `base_address` is the array itself.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int xyzzy[] = {3,1,4,1,5,9};       // Dummy array for testing.

    int *addrOf4 = &(xyzzy[2]);        // Emulate strchr-type operation.

    int index = addrOf4 - xyzzy;       // Figure out and print index.
    printf ("Index is %d\n", index);   //   Or use ptrdiff_t (see footnote a).

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Index is 2
```

As you can see, it scales correctly to give you the index regardless of the underlying type (not that it matters for `char` but it's useful to know in the general case).

So, for your specific case, if your string is `mystring` and the return value from `strchr` is `chpos`, just use `chpos - mystring` to get the index (assuming you *found* the character of course, ie, `chpos != NULL`).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As rightly pointed out in a comment, the type of a pointer subtraction is `ptrdiff_t`which, may have a different range to `int`. To be perfectly correct, the calculation and printing of the index would be better done as:

```
    ptrdiff_t index = addrOf4 - xyzzy;       // Figure out and print index.
    printf ("Index is %td\n", index);
```

Note that this will only become an issue if your arrays are large enough that the difference won't fit in an `int`. That's possible since the ranges of the two types are not directly related so, if you value portable code highly, you should use the `ptrdiff_t` variant.

Comment: should possibly mention something about dividing by sizeof(type) for arrays of types which are larger than 1 byte?

Comment: @Mike, you don't actually need that where they're the same type since C automagically scales pointer arithmetic. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: `int` is not the right type for this; it can overflow. You should be using `ptrdiff_t`, or `size_t` would be fine since the result is known to be positive.

Comment: `int` is fine for this _specific_ case since the maximum value is 6 before undefined behaviour makes it moot. For a more general case, yes, the other types should be used but it only becomes important if tour arrays are larger than can fit in an `int` But I'll make a note. BTW, ptrdiff_t is a signed type (which makes sense since you can subtract lower from higher), so size_t won't be suitable for the general case.

Answer (score 3):

Use pointer arithmetic:

```
char * pos = strchr( str, c );
int npos = (pos == NULL) ? -1 : (pos - str);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're dealing with std::string and not plain c-strings then you can use std::string::find_first_of

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/

Comment: This question is about C, not C++.

Comment: He tagged it as c++ originally, and I said "IF" :P